# Kubernetes topologySpreadConstraints doesn't distribute 3 pod evenly to 3 zone ( a b c), but places 1 to a, and 2 to b)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm trying to spread my pods to different availability zones.
I used `topologySpreadConstraints` feature with 3 replicas and such config:

```
  topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
      labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
              release: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

Worker nodes are available in 3 zones.
The problem is when I deploy it, scheduler palces one pod to `A-zone`, and 2 pods in `B-zone`.
Instead of placing one into each zone.
I understand that `maxSkew: 1`, can't be set to `0`, and it allows scheduler to schedule unevenly with +1 skewness.
But shouldn't the scheduler respect domain first? Like shouldn't it do best effort to spread 3 pods by different zones (domains) first ?
Can it be done with help of `topologySpreadConstraints` ? Or I should use `podAntiAffinity` ?

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, `maxSkew` can't be set to 0. My guess is that it's done to handle odd number of pods. In your case: one pod in `A` and two pods in `B` still respects the `maxSkew` of one so the scheduler is doing its job properly. If you know for a fact that your replica count will always be 3 (maybe on a statefulset), you can use a podAntiAffinity rule instead of your `topologySpreadContraints` but this will not work with more than one pod per zone. If you use a deployment, the simplest solution would be to increase the replica count. Something like 5 would do the trick.

Comment: In OP's case isn't the skew between zone b and c = 2?

Comment: I am not actually sure. As I understand https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#spread-constraint-definition having 1 | 2 | 0 pods had a skew of 1 compared to 1 | 1 | 1 but it's not very clear to me from the doc.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, purpose of the Kubernetes topologySpreadConstraints is to spread across your cluster based on topologyKey.

As you specified "topology.kubernetes.io/zone" topologyKey. It will evenly spread your pods across zones and if condition not satisfy it will check for maxSkew. As maxSkew is 1 it will spread 1 pod each to different zone and 1 skew specified so it will schedule that pod to any of the available pod.

If you want pods to be spreaded across different nodes you can use "kubernetes.io/hostname" key but here also maxSkew will add pods to same nodes sometimes.

If you really want to achieve High avaiibity you can use "topology.kubernetes.io/zone" topologySpreadConstraints and "kubernetes.io/hostname" antiaffinity so your pods will be scheduled on different zones and different nodes. I've added example below for your reference :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: topology-spread-anti-affinity
  name: topology-spread-anti-affinity
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: topology-spread-anti-affinity
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: topology-spread-anti-affinity
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: topology-spread-anti-affinity
                operator: DoesNotExist          
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
          whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                  - topology-spread-anti-affinity
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: nginx
```

Also, this [article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/introducing-podtopologyspread/#advanced-usage) will give you better understaning of maxSkew.